# Why is casting necessary when return type is upper-bounded?

Tags: scala

I'm writing a class that has a parameterized type `T` with an upper bound.  The class has a method that has a return type `T`:

```
import java.time.temporal.{ Temporal, TemporalAmount }
implicit class RichTemporal[T <: Temporal](t: T) {
  def + (amount: TemporalAmount): T = t.plus(amount)    // error: type mismatch
}
```

The above does not compile; the compiler complains of a type mismatch:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error] found   : java.time.temporal.Temporal
[error] required: T
```

The code only works if I explicitly call `asInstanceOf[T]`, as shown below.

```
import java.time.temporal.{ Temporal, TemporalAmount }
implicit class RichTemporal[T <: Temporal](t: T) {
  def + (amount: TemporalAmount): T = t.plus(amount).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

But why is this?  My first guess is that the compiler might not know `T` as anything more specific than a `Temporal`, and thus the call `t.plus(amount)` is actually a call to `Temporal#plus` which returns a `Temporal`, but then the call `asInstanceOf[T]` clearly shows that the compiler does know `T`'s specific type.

Taking a different route, why doesn't the compiler know that the call `t.plus(amount)` is intended to be dynamically bound, and thus returns type `T`?

Answer (score 0):

> Taking a different route, why doesn't the compiler know that the call t.plus(amount) is intended to be dynamically bound, and thus returns type T?

Because it doesn't have to return `T`, of course:

```
class MyTemporal extends Temporal {
  def plus(amount: TemporalAmount): Temporal = Instant.now()
  // other methods
}
```

is a perfectly legal implementation.